# timer scheduled swift - error with self identifier

Tags: swift

im trying to make a "sleep" function for real time updating my UI display with updating variables.
using xcode 9.2 swift 4

```
//sleep function for UI display
func sleep(time: Double, closure: @escaping (Timer) -> (Void) ) {
    var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: time, target: self, selector: #selector(closure), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    timer.invalidate()
}
```

i get this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'self'

thanks a million!

Comment: Where did you put this function?

Comment: Invalidating a timer right after being created is pointless. The closure is not executed before the timer **fires**.

Answer (score 1):

A selector statically identifies a function. You can't make a selector out of an argument.

Perhaps something like this would be better:

```
func sleep(time: Double, closure: @escaping (Timer) -> (Void) ) {
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: time, repeats: false) { timer in
        closure(timer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your error this function is might be outside of a class that is why `self` is `unresolved identifier`. Function should be inside the class body.

Next point is you are making selector in wrong way. Selector will be a method defined in same class.

Another point is you are `invalidating` the timer in next line so it will never execute.

**If your app supports `iOS Version >= 10.0`.**

```
func sleep(time: Double, closure: @escaping (Timer) -> (Void) ) {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: time, repeats: false) { (timer) in
       closure(timer)
    }
}
```

**If your app supports `iOS Version < 10.0`**

In your class make few properties:

```
typealias TimerCallBack = (_ timer: Timer) -> Void
var timer: Timer!
var callBack: TimerCallBack!
```

Then

```
func sleep(time: Double, closure: @escaping TimerCallBack) {
     self.callBack = closure
     self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: time, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFired(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc func timerFired(_ timer: Timer) {
    if callBack != nil {
        callBack(self.timer)
    }
}
```